# How To Add A Secure Login To My C# Application?

Tags: windows, authentication, ldap, credentials

I have a C# desktop app where a user enters his company ID card number as a simple form of "authentication" against a database table of valid employees. If the user is found in the table with the correct permission level, the app runs and the user can use all of the screens and menus in the application. Problem is anyone who has a valid user's ID number (perhaps from a lost or stolen ID card) can run the program and get to the data.

We want to make this application more secure. Is there a way to use the Windows ID and pwd to authenticate application users? At the very least we would like to force app users to re-enter the credentials (ID and pwd) of the currently logged in Windows user on the machine. If that fails to authenticate then the application quits and will not run.

What are my options for adding this "feature" to my app? What is the easiest way to do it? LDAP bind? Compare the Windows ID entered to the User ID found in LDAP? What is the most secure way to do it? I"m good with making my apps talk to the database, but I've never done much with Windows security or authentication, so you'll have to talk down at my level. We want to avoid storing Windows user ID's in the database. The app is a VS 2008 project, but I will someday need to do the same thing in my VS 2010 projects. Thanks!

Comment: Does your company use Active Directory?  Is this a SQL server database?

Comment: Yes, I can access AD info by calling LDAP. Yes, SQL database holds our tables and employee data.

Comment: You can use the LogonUser function to test whether a userid/password combination is valid. Note that it will generate security audits, so if somebody gives the wrong password too many times, it may lock the account. (Which is a good thing. Otherwise somebody could use your program to launch an undetected dictionary attack against the user.)